Excel does not recognize m/d/yyyy, h:mm:ss.000 AM/PM
How I can make the following date-times recognizable by Excel, at least as a date? They are from Azure and Excel doesn't recognize its own company's date-time format.
9/30/2024, 3:02:59.000 PM
11/4/2024, 12:17:09.000 PM
10/12/2024, 7:35:03.000 AM


From where you are receiving these logs? @ilhan

Here comma , is problem. So remove commas to recognize them as date. Try this formula =--SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""). Then format resultant column as desired date/time format.

Excel doesn't have logs and dates are stored as floating point numbers. How they appear depends on the cell style and locale. There's no its own company's date-time format., that's a custom format, similar to the US date format once you remove the comma. If you try to use 9/30/2024 3:02:59.000 PM outside the US then yes, you'll get an error because there's no month 30. No culture uses a comma after the date though

What does They are from Azure mean? Azure is essentially a company offering hundreds if not thousands of different services, not a single service. Did you call some service and got that as a response? Are you trying to read some log? Is that perhaps a line from a CSV file that stores dates and times next to each other? REST services serialize dates in the ISO8601 format, not this custom format, so this is certainly not an Azure service response

@Jahnavi, I was told that they are from the Azure Front Door. Exported as CSV.

Ok for any logs output, either of the below approaches would work for you. Can you check it! @ilhan

Approach-1:
The issue is with the comma (,) separator here. Remove , after exporting the logs from Azure and replace it with space or you can just remove the comma and enter it. Alternatively, you can use shortcut ctrl + H in the excel sheet to achieve the above one.

Approach: 2:
As detailed in this blog, there is a function called SUBSTITUTE which replaces the selected cell text in a given string by matching it.
Thanks @Harun24hr for providing the valid suggestion.
Use below substitute function as shown:
Note: Separator or string to be substituted with separator or string followed by cell name.
=--SUBSTITUTE(A1,","," ")

Approach-3:
You can simply go to Data >> Text to columns. A window appears as shown in the below way. Now click on required column data format and then apply.

Approach-4:
I have taken a sample query and retrieved the logs first as shown here. Once it's done, I have clicked Export to CSV to export it into local. As you mentioned, if you just want to get only the date, use this approach with KQL.
Heartbeat 
| project TimeGenerated
| extend TimeGenerated = split(tostring(TimeGenerated), "T")[0]



